# Grpc.Core becomes “Maintenance Only” immediately (May 2021)

Tags: c#

As we can read from here

https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-csharp-future/

Grpc.Core nuget package becomes “Maintenance Only” immediately (May 2021), while the Grpc.Net.Client and Grpc.AspNetCore.Server nuget packages are now the recommended gRPC implementation for .NET/C#.

Now I was wondering, when we create a gRPC Service from template in Visual Studio 2019, the service implementation uses Grpc.Core.ServerCallContext:

```
 public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, Grpc.Core.ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "Hello " + request.Name
            });
        }
```

Can we expect a different template with a different implementation, without using Grpc.Core nuget package?
Regards
Roberto

Comment: The only one who can answer this is Microsoft, and Stack Overflow is not Microsoft.

Comment: @IanKemp: I'm not from Microsoft and I've managed to provide a reasonable answer...

Comment: I'm maintainer of Grpc.Core and I can confirm that Jon Skeet's response below is very accurate. Basically, the Grpc.Core.Api nuget package and the types contained in are there to say, since it basically represents the shared API surface of both Grpc.Core and grpc-dotnet.

Comment: @JanTattermusch was there ever an official statement of doc from Microsoft about this?

Answer (score 1):

No - `Grpc.Core.ServerCallContext` is part of [`Grpc.Core.Api`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core.Api/), which is *not* going into maintenance mode, and is a dependency of `Grpc.Net.Common`.

So I wouldn't expect any changes here. The confusion is no doubt due to the naming - the `Grpc.Core.Api` package was extracted from `Grpc.Core` significantly after the first release of `Grpc.Core`, as a way of providing a common API between the two implementations. That unfortunately means we're left with names that don't make it clear which type is in which package... but in general, if you're using the MS implementation (`Grpc.Net.*`) and you see a type starting with `Grpc.Core`, it's part of `Grpc.Core.Api`.